# OSX Messages shows contact accounts as invalid

Tags: macos, messages

I had Messages.app when I got my mac a year and a half ago and it worked great.

However, since a few weeks ago all my contacts in my previous conversations appear in red (as if they do not have an account).

What's even more curious is that I can see when people are actually typing (I see the 3 dots (dis)appearing), but I only get the message on my iDevices.

Solutions I have already tried :

- Restarting messages
- Signing out/in my account
- Rebooting

I am now out of solutions, do you guy have any ideas what the problem might be?

NB : My OSX is up-to-date with 10.9.3

Edit : It also doesn't work on my iPad (iPhone is still OK, receiving iMessages as iMessages).
Edit2:  I hoped updating to Yosemite would help. But no :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually solved my problem was : disabling iMessage on a computer where my account was logged in (a Mac with Mountain Lion).

Before that, I had already disabled (and re-enabled) my iMessage account on every other device.

I'm pretty confident about the fact that it solved my problem because it was the last one where it was enabled. I've read many times that disabling-enable on EVERY device may solve the problem. So if this doesn't work, think HARD there might be one last device (Friend's mac, siblings' iPod etc).

Answer (score 0):

It's only a guess, but your scenario matches an issue I had with my iDevices and Message on the Mac too. See also the discussion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/139709/86244).

What resolved the issue was activating the `iMessage` Setting on my iPhone via `Settings > Messages`.

Strangely this does effect the Messages send/receive on the Mac as well!

Can you verify this?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your internet connection? If you have Wifi you would most likely use it for your Mac and iPad, but your iPhone would use mobile data (if you have it.) Also if you are using your work's internet connection the IT department may have blocked access to the iMessage servers. Alternatively, check with your ISP to see if they

- have blocked access to iMessage servers or
- can verify anybody else having the same issue.

Comment: Definitely not an internet connection problem.